# For bulk input, how to update matching rows and insert unmatched rows as new rows?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'employee' with two columns 'firstname' and 'lastname' and it has unique constraint on 'lastname' column.

If I am sending more than one row, how can I update matched rows from input and create new rows for unmatched.

Existing data in database:

```
|id  | firstname   | lastname  |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | John        | Doe       |
```

Input rows:

```
| firstname | lastname  |
+-----------+-----------+
| John1     | Doe       | 
| Bar       | foo       |
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
INSERT INTO Identification (firstname,lastname)
    (VALUES 
    ('John1','Doe'),
    ('Bar','foo')) as u2 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT lname_unique_constraint 
DO UPDATE
    SET 
    firstname = u2.firstname
RETURNING Id;
```

It gives me this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"

If the script works fine, it should leave database in the below state:

```
|id  | firstname   | lastname  |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | John1       | Doe       |
|  2 | Bar         | foo       |
```

NOTE:
I am using PostgreSQL 10.6 and `id` column is of type number and set to auto sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `EXCLUDED`:

> [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)
>
> Note that the special **excluded table is used to reference values originally proposed for insertion**

```
INSERT INTO Identification (firstname,lastname)
    VALUES 
    ('John1','Doe'),
    ('Bar','foo') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT fname_unique_constraint 
DO UPDATE
    SET 
    firstname = EXCLUDED.firstname
RETURNING Id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1b4888ae3a8428594f0b16f6360964d6)**